# how to store matched elements from list in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, list

```
how to convert ascii value of 49 to actual char in java
```

my code is below and i am trying to store elements from list which is not start with prefix a or g

```
 void display(){
    String[] inpArray={"apple","orange","grapes"};
    LinkedList<String> listOne = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(inpArray));
    LinkedList<String> listTwo = new LinkedList<String>();
    listTwo.add("melon");
    listTwo.add("apple");
    listTwo.add("mango");
    String[] result1 = {};
    for(String res : listOne){

    if(res.startsWith("a")||res.startsWith("g")){
        System.out.println("--> "+res);
    }else{
        System.out.println("** "+res);
        //result1 = res;//unable to store in string array or to list
        // here i have to add all strings how to do that please help me
    }
```

Comment: `listOne.stream().filter(s -> s.startsWith("a") || s.startsWith("g")).collect(toList())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store the elements into an array, you can put them into a `List` first, then convert the `List` to array by `List.toArray`:

```
LinkedList<String> linkedList = new LinkedList<>();
for (String res : listOne) {
    if (res.startsWith("a") || res.startsWith("g")) {
        System.out.println("--> " + res);
    } else {
        System.out.println("** " + res);
        linkedList.add(res);
    }
}
String[] result1 = new String[linkedList.size()];
linkedList.toArray(result1);
```

Comment: Hi John thanks for your time i have updated my code accordingly but getting below error
LinkedList<String> linkedList = null;//i have declared new array

result1 = linkedList.toArray(new String[0]);//this line throwing null pointer exception

Comment: `return linkedList.toArray(new String[linkedList.size()])`.

Comment: John let me try again one moment appreciat your time

Comment: @BoristheSpider `void display()`, seems the OP does not want to return the array...

Comment: getting below out put for result1
system.out.println(result1) displays below result
[Ljava.lang.String;@15db9742

Comment: @user2926683 See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array

Comment: Hi BoristheSpider i just need to store elements from list i am not sure which methos suits ...

Comment: I did john but still the output is [Ljava.lang.String;@15db9742

LinkedList<String> linkedList = new LinkedList<String>();//i have declared new array
  for(String res : listOne){
   
  if(res.startsWith("a")||res.startsWith("g")){
   //System.out.println("--> "+res);
  }else{
   //System.out.println("** "+res);
   
   result1 = linkedList.toArray(new String[0]);//this line throwing null
   //pointer exception
   System.out.println(result1);
   
  }

Comment: @user2926683     Try this   `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result1));`

Comment: Now out put displays only square brackets as below

[]

Comment: Hi john thanks much all i need to do is to store unmatched elements from list 
as a begginner i tried to store it into array but storing it into new list easiest way found from you any how i have learned two way of storing from you.
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

```
Please find the code for storing the element in String array using index i;

package com.test.stackoverflow;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        display();
    }

    public static void display() {
        String[] inpArray = { "apple", "orange", "grapes" };
        List<String> listOne = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(inpArray));
        List<String> listTwo = new ArrayList<String>();
        listTwo.add("melon");
        listTwo.add("apple");
        listTwo.add("mango");
        String[] result1 = new String[listOne.size()];
        int i =0;
        for (String res : listOne) {

            if (res.startsWith("a") || res.startsWith("g")) {
                System.out.println("--> " + res);
            } else {
                System.out.println("** " + res);
                result1[i++] = res;
            }
        }

        for(String val : result1){
            System.out.println("Value"+val);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: nice bro instead i am done after fetched listone elements i have used add function to merge two list any how you did it even simpler thanks for new logic
learned from you......